# Composition Series of $A_4 \times S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Please help me with the following question:

Find the composition series of $A_4 \times S_5$ and prove that this series is indeed a composition series.
Afterwards, find a group with the same composition factor as for $A_4 \times S_5$ which isn't isomorphic to $A_4 \times S_5$.

I tried to use the following series: $A_4 \times S_5\unrhd A_4 \times A_5\unrhd \{(1),(1 2)(3 4),(1 3)(2 4),(1 4)(2 3)\} \times A_5 \unrhd$
$\{(1),(1 2)(3 4)\} \times A_5 \unrhd \{(1)\} \times A_5 \unrhd\{(1)\} \times \{(1)\}$.
However, I'm not sure I'm correct and I couldn't find a group with the same composition factor as for $A_4 \times S_5$ which isn't isomorphic to $A_4 \times S_5$.

Comment: I did not understand this part 'find a composition series and show that it is indeed a compositionseries'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compsition series is true.

Set $G=A_4\times H$ where $H\cong A_5\times Z_2$ then you can easily see that it has same composition factor but they are not ismorphic.

Comment: @SpamIAm : Thanks for the suggestion, fixed now.